# after changing scenes, hidden objects are no longer hidden

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, renderer, unity3d-2dtools

I'm new to Unity and C# so bear with me please. I have several scenes where the player can move at will and in one there are imageobjects that I want hidden when mouseclicked. Right now I have added a script to one imageobject where I use `renderer.enabled = false;` to hide it. When the player moves back to that scene it is not hidden anymore. What would be the right way to do this?

//------EDITED PART-----------
Now it works :)

```
public static bool showIt = true;
    void Start () {
        renderer.enabled = showIt;
        print (showIt);
    }
    void OnMouseDown (){
        showIt = false;
        renderer.enabled = showIt;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use static variables to persist the objects's state? You could use PlayerPrefs, but it's not the optimal method. Set your boolean variable to record the state using static initialization, then use your Start() method to initialize your variable and set the value(s). Remember before your LoadLevel() you must persist the value to the the given variable (or PlayerPrefs.Set* if you go that route). Remember if you persist in Update() or OnGUI() or FixedUpdate() there is significant cost.

Comment: Thanks a million :D  Above is my code and it seems to be working. Do I need to add every object I want hidden it's own script or can they all be handled from the same?

Answer (score 0):

why not gameObject.SetActive(false) instead of renderer.enabled = false ?

Comment: It does the same, the object still appears when the scene is re-entered.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this using PlayerPrefs:

```
    public class RenderController : MonoBehaviour {

        // Check PlayerPrefs in Awake() to see if renderer should be enabled
        void Awake(){
            if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("rendererOn") == 0) {
                renderer.enabled = true;
            }
            else
                renderer.enabled = false;
        }

        void OnMouseDown(){

            // If the renderer is enabled when clicked then disable renderer
            if (renderer.enabled == true) {
                renderer.enabled = false;
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("rendererOn",1);// Set state to 1(false)in PlayerPrefs
            }

            // If the renderer is disabled when clicked then enable it
            else if(renderer.enabled == false){
                renderer.enabled = true;
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("rendererOn",0);// Set state to 0(true)in PlayerPrefs
            }
        }  
    }
```

I tested it in Unity and it works. Basically just writing the enabled/disabled state of the renderer componenet to PlayerPrefs and every time the object loads it checks to see what the last state was. Remember to set rendererOn global variable equal to 0, as I did above, if you want it enabled when the game loads for the first time.

Comment: I thought about using playerPrefs too but AmitApollo's answer is simpler so I'll go with that but I'm taking your example too, I think I'll still need it somewhere :)